# Drag to reorder UITableViewCell in iOS 8 won't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ios8

I have a UITableView with cells that I want to drag to reorder. I didn't want the default handles on the cell, so I removed the view but left the same hit area in place by following [this walkthrough](http://b2cloud.com.au/tutorial/reordering-a-uitableviewcell-from-any-touch-point/). I've implemented all of the necessary delegate and datasource methods for this to work and it does a perfect job in iOS 7 but will not work in iOS 8.

From what I've found, the only suggested solution is to update Xcode and the SDK. Unfortunately, because a third party plugin that this project is dependent on I cannot update to Xcode 6 or the iOS 8 SDK.

Has anyone else had this problem? Does drag to reorder work just fine for anyone else?

I have added:

`- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;`

and

`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath {`

This does work just fine on iOS 7 but will not work on iOS8.

Comment: "so I removed the view but left the same hit area in place" So, you break the interface and then complain that the interface is broken?

Comment: I followed a walkthrough on how to adjust the reorder control handle. And it does work just fine on iOS 7, so I figure there is a reasonable expectation that it would continue to work on iOS 8.

Comment: I would figure just the opposite. If you do something hacky that Apple clearly isn't expecting or intending you to do, you should expect it to break when Apple closes whatever the hole is that you managed to creep through...!

Comment: I think sometimes there are valid reasons to "break" the interface. I've been forced to to this because my app is used in a light-sensative environment where some of the default UI elements (including the reorder handle) would harm photographic materials.

Comment: Reading the walkthrough the private API is being referenced (looking for the `UITableViewCellReorderControl`). The view hierarchy has changed in iOS8 so it's not working. No surprise. You can try walking the new hierarchy to see how it has changed.